# powershell exchange commands in c# - runspace limits

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

lately i've been creating some module in .net project which sends commands by remote powershell to exchange server.
I have many problems with runespace - sometimes it's state is broken, sometimes I  exceeded the maximum number of connections allowed(3)

I don't know how to do it.
The code below is not really fine, but it works better than earlier code - so please don't look at quality at the moment

The first class is responsible for returning runespace (and powershell connection) - i have registered this class as a singleton (it's webapi project)

```
public class PowershellCommandEnvironment : IPowershellCommandEnvironment, IDisposable
{
    readonly (string user, string password) powerShellAuth;
    private static Runspace _runspace = null;
    WSManConnectionInfo _connectionInfo;
    

    public PowershellCommandEnvironment()
    {
        powerShellAuth.user = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ExchangePowerShellUser");
        powerShellAuth.password = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ExchangePowerShellPassword");

        SecureString secureStrin = new NetworkCredential("", powerShellAuth.password).SecurePassword;
        var creds = new PSCredential(powerShellAuth.user, secureStrin);
        _connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", creds);
        _connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        _connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 2;
        _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(_connectionInfo);
        _runspace.StateChanged += _runspace_StateChanged;


    }

    private void _runspace_StateChanged(object sender, RunspaceStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var state = _runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State;
        switch (state)
        {
            case RunspaceState.Broken:
                _runspace.Close();
                _runspace.Dispose();
                _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(_connectionInfo);
                break;

            case RunspaceState.Opening:
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                break;

            case RunspaceState.BeforeOpen:
                _runspace.Open();
                break;
        }
    }

    public Runspace GetRunspace()
    {
      
            while (_runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State != RunspaceState.Opened)
            {

                OpenRunSpaceTimeExceededAttempt(0);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            return _runspace;
        
      
    }

    private void OpenRunSpaceTimeExceededAttempt(int attempt)
    {
        if (attempt > 2)
            return;

  
        try
        {
            var state = _runspace?.RunspaceStateInfo.State;
            if (_runspace == null || state == RunspaceState.Closed)
            {
                _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(_connectionInfo);
                _runspace.Open();
            }


            if (state == RunspaceState.BeforeOpen)
                _runspace.Open();


   
            if (!(state == RunspaceState.Opened))
            {
                OpenRunSpaceTimeExceededAttempt(attempt+1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Please wait for"))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
            OpenRunSpaceTimeExceededAttempt(attempt + 1);
        }
    }

 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _runspace.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The second class is PowershellComand which is responsible for executing commands

```
protected abstract Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
        protected abstract string Command { get; }

        private static Runspace _runspace = null;
        public PowershellCommand(IPowershellCommandEnvironment powershellCommandEnvironment)
        {
            _runspace = powershellCommandEnvironment.GetRunspace();
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            
        }
      
        public T Execute(int attemp=0)
        {
            if (attemp > 2)
                return null;

            try
            {
                using (var powershell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    powershell.Runspace = _runspace;
                        
                    powershell.AddCommand(Command);
                    foreach (var param in Parameters)
                    {
                        powershell.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
                    }
                    Collection<PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();
                    powershell.Runspace.Dispose();
                    return Map(result);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string logMessage = $"Command ${Command} not suceeded.{Environment.NewLine} {ex.Message} {ex.InnerException?.Message}";
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, logMessage);
                int sleep = 5000;
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Please wait for"))
                {
                    sleep = 10000;
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "waiting 10000 seconds (powershell command time exceeded");
                 
                }
                Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                return Execute(attemp+1);
            }
        }

        protected abstract T Map(IEnumerable<PSObject> psobj);
```

This class is derived by specific classes which have overrided Command (like Get-Group, Get-User, etc) with parameters

It works but often there are some errors from powershell remote :
-exceeded limit of runespace (i think i create only one - if it's broken im disposing it and creating new one)
-exeeding time litims - i have to wait X seconds after latest command invoke...
-bad xml - this is the strangest thing - remote powershell answers me that i've send wrong xml data - its occur seldom and is fully randomized

I know the code is a bit obfuscaded, but when i've tried the simplest approach which i found on the internet there were really much more erros related to time limits and runspace limits

The commands will be executed often - like it's possible that 5 users can execute some command in same time.

using remote powershell is only possible way to operate on security enabled mail enabled groups on exchange, so i can not use graph api...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by combining locks, and singleton ;)